# pip install iceberg - Preparing metadata (setup.py) error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pip, python-3.8, apache-iceberg

Command:

```
pip install iceberg
```

Returns this error:

```
C:\Users\abc>pip install iceberg
Collecting iceberg
  Using cached iceberg-0.4.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
```

When I'm trying to install the `iceberg` library.

Comment: **1.** [Apache Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/) has nothing in common with [ICEBERG](https://pypi.org/project/iceberg/). Which one do you want to install? If you mean the former like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74898057/7976758) then `pip install iceberg` will not help you, it installs a different ICEBERG, not Apche's one. If you mean the latter you should remove the unrelated tag. **2.** Please show the full text of the error.